# Trello Completed Lists gets larger with time

Tags: trello

I started using Trello very recently. I used a very simple template with a "To Do" list, a "Working On" list and a "completed" list.

Once I complete the cards, they get loaded in the Completed List. So the Completed List will grow larger with time.

How can I manage this issue of growing the completed list?

Comment: You can archive the list if I remember correct. Check 3-dot menu on the list card.

Comment: Yes, we can easily achieve the list. Yet, the archived lists can not be inspected for their cards until it is taken back to the board.